# I cannot display App Icon using flutter_launcher_icons

Tags: xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies

App Icon is not displayed in Xcode's Runner.
Perhaps the reason is that it is not set here properly.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.10.0
> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.4, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm, locale ja-JP)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run :

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

Comment: I tried it . but It can not set .

Comment: I did add new image . can you check

Comment: what error do you see when hover on those yellow error in new image?

Comment: The file '87.png' for the image set "AppIcon" does not exits

Comment: The app icon set "AppIcon" has 21 unassigned children